# Integrate LinkedIn with Monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, linkedin-api

I have a problem in `LinkedIn` integration in `Monotouch`. i have integrated `Facebook` successfully  using Logged In Session like as following :

```
internal void SaveAuthorization ()
        {
            var defaults = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;
            defaults ["FBAccessTokenKey"] = new NSString (facebook.AccessToken);
            defaults ["FBExpirationDateKey"] = facebook.ExpirationDate;
            defaults.Synchronize ();
        }
```

or using like :

```
    public class SessionDelegate : FBSessionDelegate 
        {
            FacebookLoginViewController container;

            public SessionDelegate (FacebookLoginViewController  container)
            {
                this.container = container;
            }

            public override void DidLogin ()
            {
                container.ShowLoggedIn ();
                container.SaveAuthorization ();
            }
            public override void DidLogout ()
            {
                container.ClearAuthorization ();
                //container.ShowLoggedOut ();
            }

            public override void DidNotLogin (bool cancelled)
            {
                // TODO: Implement - see: http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?
link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.ModelAttribute
            }

            public override void SessionInvalidated ()
            {
                // TODO: Implement - see: http://go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?
link=T%3aMonoTouch.Foundation.ModelAttribute
            }
        }
```

Now I want to use same for LinkedIn. how can i complete it.?

thanks in advance